# Show that for any $\mu$-measurable set $E$ we have $\mu(A\cap E) = \mu(B\cap E)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be an outer measure on $X$. Let $A\subset X$ and assume there is a $\mu$-measurable set $B\supset A$ with $\mu(B)=\mu(A) <\infty$. Show that for any $\mu$-measurable set $E$ we have $\mu(A\cap E) = \mu(B\cap E)$

---

By the definition we have $\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap E)+\mu(A\cap E^c)$ and $\mu(B)=\mu(B\cap E)+\mu(B\cap E^c)$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap B)+\mu(E\cap B^c)$

How can I conclude the proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trivial that $\mu^*(A\cap E)\le\mu^*(B\cap E)$, so let's check the other inequality:
$$\mu^*(A\cap E)=\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(A\setminus E)\ge\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B\setminus E)=\mu^*(B)-\mu^*(B\setminus E)=\mu^*(B\cap E)$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirly sure, but lets give it a try..

one inequallity is obvious from monotonic:
$\mu(A\cap E)\le \mu(B\cap E)$

for the other one, consider the sub-additivity:
$\mu(B\cap E)\le\mu((B\cap E)\cap A)+\mu((B\cap E)\cap A^c)=\mu(A\cap E)+\mu((B-A)\cap E)$

So all's left is to show $\mu(E\cap(B-A))=0$. I think that it should be pretty easy to complete and I'll probably do it very soon.